# Unix offset with fullCalendar difference

Tags: javascript, jquery, fullcalendar, momentjs

I want to place a check when I'm getting a momentjs instance through fullCalendar.

I'm at the eventRender callback

```js
var calendar = $('#calendar').fullCalendar('getCalendar');
var atime = calendar.moment();
var atime_h = atime.format("HH:mm");
atime = atime.unix();

var start = calendar.moment(event.start);
var start_u = start.unix();
var start_h = start.format("HH:mm");

console.log(atime);
console.log(atime_h);
console.log(start_u);
console.log(start_h);
```

Now what that logs is this:

```
1408024477
15:54
1407888000
00:00
```

1408024477 == Thu Aug 14 15:54:37 2014 == is correct

But 1407888000 == Wed Aug 13 02:00:00 2014, where I would expect 00:00 instead of 02:00

So there's a difference between the event .unix()/format.() and the moment I created.

Anyone got a clue what's going on?

**Edit:**

So what happens is that if I create two new moments: moment() and a moment().utc(), I get the same timestamp for both. But when I then display them, there is a difference of two hours.

The .utc one returns two hours in the past, the one without the correct one for me. The timestamp is not two hours back.

But with the event.start (which has `_isUTC=true`, the timestamp is two hours in the future (!), and it displays it correct when formatted.

So maybe I need to have my event.start to be not UTC and two hours back somehow?

**Edit by request in comment, this is what I use now:**

```
                var start = calendar.moment(event.start);
                console.log(start);

                start_utc = new Date(start.year(), start.month(), start.date(),  start.hour(), start.minute(), start.second());
                var start = calendar.moment(start_utc);
                console.log(start);
```

Comment: Is your event.start in utc? Because if it's not this might just be a timezone issue. Can you give us the console.log result of event.start, without the HH:mm formatting?

Comment: Yes it probably has something to do with the timezone: Date {Thu Aug 14 2014 02:00:00 GMT+0200} I'm trying some stuff out at the moment.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try converting your event.start date to utc first, here's how to do it in vanilla js:

```
start_utc = new Date(start.getUTCFullYear(), start.getUTCMonth(), start.getUTCDate(),  start.getUTCHours(), start.getUTCMinutes(), start.getUTCSeconds());
```

Then you can call `.unix()` on it and it should give you the expected timestamp.

Comment: I ended up using the moment functions instead like start.month() inside the new Date(), but it did the trick. Thanks!

Comment: I've pasted it in my question at the bottom.